# How many bytes will the following pointer write?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am a little confused about the concept of pointers writing to pointers, and I have a question on a practice exam for my C programming class. For example, lets say I have a `char* q = 0x1000`. The question then says `char** qq = &q`, `int** pp = qq`. If I execute the command `**pp = ...` how many bytes will it write? One or four?

Comment: Pointers don't _'write bytes'_?!?

Comment: Unclear, are you doing `int** pp = qq` or simply `**pp = something`?

Comment: How many bytes are used for pointer/reference values is implementation dependent!

Comment: ...by `write` you mean: "how large will the assignment be"? ... also this is why I dislike programming classes... the question should be: why is this a bad Idea?  because types hold up to 3 types of information: 1 signedness, 2 level of reference/dereference, and 3 size... this type of assignment potentially changes all three and makes very hard to find bugs.

Comment: Is this a valid 'char* q = 0x1000' assignment? When I run the code, Segmentation Fault error occurs. (MacOS) c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0

Answer (score 5):

It will write sizeof(int) bytes (typically 4). Dereferencing is always based on the type of the variable you're dereferencing, NOT the underlying type.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought, but I just wanted to make sure. Thank you!